# alguien sabe si next 14 ya no permite exportar paginas estaticas?

Tags: next.js

tengo un proyecto de landing page que había hecho hace unos 2 meses
y ahora intenté ejecutar `npm run build` y me aparece sin estilos

cree un proyecto nuevo en **next 14** y lo único que puse en `next.config.js`   `output: "export"`, y me aparece la carpeta out pero sin estilos css

alguien sabe si vercel ya deshabilitó esta opcion en next?